# How to show Google Map in Android Device

Tags: android, android-maps

I have made an app in which I am **working with Google Map**, and I am *able to view map in Emulator*, but while I do test on device i am *just getting plan grid*, why?

But in Emulator i can view map in satellite or normal mode....

what could be the reason, please help me...

In AndroidManifest.xml:

```
 <uses-library android:name='com.google.android.maps'/>
```

and i am also *using my Map API Key*....

Comment: Here is your [homework](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=android+map+blank+grid).

Answer (score 2):

you to need to get signed Md5 finger print for getting tiles on Android device, you are currently using Debug key for displaying tiles on emulator..

take help from here

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/mapkey

Answer (score 0):

You are using debug key for map that's why it is showing u grid on map when you are using map try to debug you app using debugging mode on device.